# Capturing a letter and shift in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to allow the user to do one of two things via an input field classed `.noNumbers`:

1. Press and hold shift along with a letter
2. Just pressing a letter

So far my code only allows pressing a letter but if shift is held, the letters will not go through. I'm not sure why that would happen.

This is my code so far:

```
$(".noNumbers").keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which < 97 || e.which > 122) 
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    var amount = $(this).val().length;
    var limit = 2;

    if(amount > limit)
    {
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`97` and `122` are the ASCII values of the lowercase letters `a` and `z`.  If you want uppercase letters, they would be ASCII values `65` through `90`.

```
var isLetter = false;

if( (e.which >= 97 && e.which <= 122) || (e.which >= 65 && e.which <= 90) ) 
{
    isLetter = true;
}

if(!isLetter) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

However, you probably also want to allow <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and <kbd>Delete</kbd>, or else your user will be stuck with three characters they cannot delete.  You should also consider how you will handle pasting a value into the field.